# Node.js script hangs on require, but works fine in the REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, lightstreamer

I'm running `node.js` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I appear to be getting different behaviour using `require` depending on whether I use it in the REPL or in a script. Specifically, I used `npm` to download [`lightstreamer-client-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightstreamer-client-node). Now, I open up a terminal and do the following:

```
colin@colin-XPS-15-9550:~$ node
> var x = require('lightstreamer-client-node')
```

This works perfectly.

Now I want to use this package in a script. I create a text file `node_test.js` containing just the line:

```
var x = require('lightstreamer-client-node')
```

and I open up a terminal and run the command:

```
colin@colin-XPS-15-9550:~$ node /home/colin/node_test.js
```

This hangs indefinitely on a blinking cursor.

I'm brand new to `node.js` and `JavaScript` so perhaps this is expected behaviour. I've done some reading about the `require` function and can't seem to find an explanation for it. Note that if I replace `lightstreamer-client-node` with some other node module, e.g. `safe-buffer`, then everything works fine, whether I use REPL or script.

Comment: what happens if you put a second line ... like `console.log('hello world')` after the require statement?

Comment: Have you tried putting more code in your file? I was able to `require` it, and with the require being the only thing in the file it did hang like you said. However, I put a bunch of random print statements in. They printed fine, but then hung. I then added `process.exit(0);` to the end of the script and it exited normally. Perhaps the hang is expected of that specific package.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for responding. I just placed `console.log('message 1')` before the `require` and `console.log('message 2')` after the `require`. Both statements printed, then the blinking cursor.

Comment: so, it's not the require that is preventing the node process from ending - it's something in that library that does that - possibly for a good reason - who knows, but you can safely write code that uses that library

Comment: @tycrek I just duplicated that on my machine. Thanks for responding. Perhaps it is supposed to happen. LightStreamer is for establishing a bi-directional connection with a server, so I guess it sort of makes sense? I'm brand new to this area of programming, so my question is perhaps a bit naive.

Comment: @JaromandaX Awesome thanks. My question may have been naive.

Comment: It's not a naive question at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process seems to hang because the library lightstreamer-client installs a timer, with the function setInterval, for its internal activities, and nodejs doesn't allow a graceful shutdown when there are active tasks. So the only way to terminate the script is by using the function process.exit.